# Link rel='import' breaks Router

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm experimenting with dart-polymer apps and have run into a few issues.

Is there a way to inject template declaration of a custom element through code? The docs currently specify the following method:

```html
<link rel="import" href="my_element.html">
```

I'm trying to use the Route package (specifically 'package:route/client.dart'), and importing an html module via this method seems to break the router, so:

```dart
main() {
    var router = new Router()
        ..addHandler(homeUrl, showHome)
        ..addHandler(signinUrl, showSignin)
        ..listen();
}
```

fails to execute the handlers when I navigate to the Url specified. If I remove the html import, the Router works fine.
Any way around this?

Comment: You might want to add more code to your question because there should not be a problem with doing this. It's probably something inside my_element.dart that is causing the whole application to stop.

Comment: Thanks, @Nathanial for your comment. Sorry I saw this much later. In the meantime, the new dart build I was using broke the ability to use link rels within partials. So I had to temporarily suspend the dart project. Thanks, anyway.